# Countdown Circle Animation starts only when tab is active

Tags: node.js, reactjs, timer, geometry, countdown

I use the react countdown circle timer package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-circle-timer

Main issue:
my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INckP.jpg
video example: https://youtu.be/TYqoXDEksog

My timer in backend starts and I set isPlaying={true} when 2nd player joins game.

If I am in the tab and my timer starts, the circle animation starts aswell normally as you see in the video.

But if I am in a different tab or better said, if the tab is not active, the circle animation wont start even if I set isPlaying={true}. It only starts if the tab is active / if i come back to the tab.

https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer/issues/31
I have exactly the same issue, need to implement this solution from the owner in my app.

If you know how to help please leave a message!

Comment: most timers in javascript are stopped while the tab is not active, you could set the timer based on the backend value after the tab becomes active again. Have a look at `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", <your method>)`

Comment: would you be able to help me? How can I message you